# Python PIL Save Image to Different "Folder" on Amazon S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library

I need to save my avatar to the "avatar" folder inside my Amazon S3 bucket.

```
Bucket
-Static
--Misc
-Media
--Originals
--Avatars
```

Currently, when I create the avatar, it is saved to the `Originals` "folder". My goal is to save it to the `Avatars` "folder".

Here is my code for creating and saving the avatar

```
    def create_avatar(self):
    import os
    from PIL import Image
    from django.core.files.storage import default_storage as storage

    if not self.filename:
        return ""
    file_path = self.filename.name

    filename_base, filename_ext = os.path.splitext(file_path)
    thumb_file_path = "%s_thumb.jpg" % filename_base

    if storage.exists(thumb_file_path):
        return "exists"
    try:
        # resize the original image and return url path of the thumbnail
        f = storage.open(file_path, 'r')
        image = Image.open(f)
        width, height = image.size

        size = 128, 128
        image.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

        f_thumb = storage.open(thumb_file_path, "w")
        image.save(f_thumb, "JPEG", quality=90)
        f_thumb.close()
        return "success"
    except:
        return "error"
```

Comment: I assume you are using django-storages

Answer (score 0):

I was able to save the avatar to the desired "*folder*" by renaming the file path with a simple python `replace()` function.

This did the trick if anyone else ever need to "move" a file within the S3 bucket

```
thumb_file_path = thumb_file_path.replace('originals/', 'avatar/')
```